# How can I sort iMessage images by name?

Tags: imessage, imessage-extension

When I add images to `Sticker Pack`, they added unsorted. I can sort them manually, one-by-one, but how to sort all of them by name for one time?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution.

**Correct Way:** (Important note - sort files in Finder correctly)

[image]

[image]

**Wrong way**

[image]
[image]